# Allow only one move to be made each turn at Tic Tac Toe

Tags: php, html, forms, tic-tac-toe

I'm making a standard Tic-Tac-Toe game, **php only.** Here's a screenshot of how the board looks like aswell as the buttons: https://gyazo.com/70342d90765e60ecfab82938d20a70da
The only problem, as you can see, is that you can submit 3 "'O's" or "'X's" in the same turn. 
The only solution to this problem that I can think of is something like this:

```
      if ($a == 'X' && ($b == 'X' || $c == 'X' || $d == 'X' || 
      $e == 'X' || $f == 'X' || $g == 'X' || $h == 'X' || $i == 'X'))
      echo "You can only choose one square!"
```

where $a-$i represents each of the 9 forms and 'X' represents the value of the form. The only problem is that this technique would require like 30 lines of code. Furthermore, the form would still be submitted. I want it to NOT send if they choose more than one forms on their turn. Does anyone have any other solutions? 
I didn't know what part of my code to share so here's the full code if it's to anyones interest: http://pastebin.com/McRefCa9

Comment: Because it's a php class I'm attending. Not allowed to use anything else ;)

Comment: Use buttons instead of select. Each can be submitted independently.

Comment: @Torchify: Nice and simple. I was about to suggest to not use select fields, but present an actual “playing field” that for the current player has their selected fields marked as an “O”, and an “X” for their opponent’s – and use radio buttons for the rest of the fields, that they can still choose from. (That both players would see their own pieces as the “O”s and their opponent’s as the “X”s, should no matter much. Or, if that is considered undesirable, a “custom radio button” solution could be used, there’s enough of them out there.)

Comment: For instance: 
`<form method=post action=luffis.php>
<button type="submit" name="ruta1" value="<?php echo $spelare;?>"><?php echo $spelare;?></button>
</form>`

Comment: @CBroe radio button idea would work.

Comment: Should mention that with the independent button method you'll have a bunch of unassigned variables on the submit so you would need to store the result somewhere. In your original `select` method you are storing the values back into the form so they are resubmitted each time. Maybe its best to keep the `select` and then echo a `disabled` attribute to the selects that have already been picked.

Comment: You can always use a hidden input field to transport the previous choices. Unless of course you want to prevent manipulation by the user, for that you’d have to store each choice server-side anyway. (But that’s perhaps beyond the scope of the class he’s attending.)

Comment: @Torchify I like the idea with the buttons, but as you said, I'll have to rechange my entire if(isset($_POST['skicka'])) part. What do you mean by "echo a disabled attribute to the selects that have already been picked"? New to php so kindergarten level is appriciated :)

Comment: any form element can be disabled with a "disabled" attribute on the form tag. So for instance `<select disabled></select>` would be a grayed out option